# UI Improvements when editing your Application Registration

Tags: feature-request

I went to update my application's profile and I got confused by some of the labels, titles, etc.

Here are some suggestions:

Applications page
[http://imgur.com/lV424.png](https://imgur.com/lV424.png)

Edit application page
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY9eb.png

Comment: I personally agree with both of those - they seem simple enough. (And rather obvious!) :)